# Magento 2.2.6 CMS homepage content goes here

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6, nginx, static-content

I am getting CMS homepage content goes here. content on the front page as well as on the admin panel with no images and any other content,
how to resolve this issue.

Run below commands also

```
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +
sudo find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx .
sudo chmod u+x bin/magento
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* pub/static/* generated/*
mage setup:upgrade
mage s:d:c
mage s:s:d
mage c:f
```

I am using
Magento 2.2.6
centos 7
PHP 7.0 with FPM
NGINX
SSL on

Comment: Do you see something in logs? Nginx or php-fpm log as well as in Magentos logs? (if not enabled, please enable logging and check for errors)

Comment: I have checked for error but there is no such error inside for nginx= /va/log/nginx/error.log and for php-fpm=/var/log/php-fpm/error.log Also have enabled magento mode to developer and deployed static content still no error. I found one thing more intersting all static files location doesn't contain pub/ folder path.

Comment: static files URLs are like this domain+/static/version1606727911/_cache/merged/d8d0ccd00abc842e5491d4f81f17b9ca.min.css" NO pub/ folder in URL

Comment: Here is the access-log of site https://imgur.com/vTKw8TJ

Comment: I don't now what your settings are and for waht reason a redirect to `/bigapple2` is done, but your static assets are available without the `/bigapple2` in the path. If the referenced js and css files wouldn't contain that, you would most likely get the correctly displayed pages. So check your server configurations as awell as your Magento configurations and get those in sync.